# How to detect when a certain time has passed in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, timer

I need a way to finding out when the time from 0 ends up as 4 secs.

My code is as follows:

I have a global variable called weightdelaycount, which is incremented every 1000 intervals.

```
Private Sub Timer_weightcheck_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer_weightcheck.Tick
    weightdelaycount = weightdelaycount + 1
End Sub
```

Now I have the do while loop that runs infinitely and only stops depending on two conditions. Either the weightchange = True or if the clock = 4 secs.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    weightdelaycount = 0
    Timer_weightcheck.Enabled = True
    Do While 1

        If (weightchange() = True ) Then
            Timer_weightcheck.Enabled = False
            Exit Do
        End If

        If (weightdelaycount = 4) Then
            Timer_weightcheck.Enabled = False
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    MessageBox.Show(weightdelaycount)

End Sub
```

From the routine above you see that I'm using exit Do to exit the loop if the two conditions are met. The problem is that if the weightchange() is not True and 4 seconds passed the systems doesn't stop. I can put a delay in there and then it works, but I need to be accurate with the values that I get for the weight from a scale. If I put a delay, then the values will not be accurate. Is there a way to solve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Start by turning on option strict.  Your button code's loop prevents the timer from processing any Tick events.  It will also prevent any event from a scale from being processed (if that is what is going on). You could set a 4 second timer (without a loop) and check if the weight changed then to match the same criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a timer, you could use a stopwatch. This code will loop until 4000ms after the stopwatch has started. You'll never get it to stop **exactly** on 4000ms because of the time it takes to run through the the Do..Loop(minimal really), but I presume a couple of ms after is close enough.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim weightdelaycount = 0
    Dim timer As New Stopwatch
    timer.Start()
    Do
        If (weightchange() = True) Then
            timer.Stop()
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop Until timer.ElapsedMilliseconds > 4000
    timer.Stop()
    MessageBox.Show(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds)
End Sub
```

Comment: This solution works but freezes the form until the stopwatch finishes

Comment: @rmed1na if you need to do events, use `Application.DoEvents()` - it moves the  program flow to the places that "need" it.